# 2009 Hyundai Sonata sometimes kicks when switching to heavy gear while breaking

Tags: automatic-transmission, hyundai, sonata, transmission-fluid

I have a very clean 2009 Hyundai Sonata GLS that I bought June last year. It had around 59k on it back then and now has around 64k. I usually use it to commute relatively short distances in a small town and occasionally for longer drives to the San Francisco and back. I took it to the dealership for an oil change a month ago and their inspection reported everything as being in perfect condition.

It usually shift to a heavier gear (I guess the heaviest one it has) as the speed comes below 22-3 MPH when braking, this shift however feels like a kick sometimes and isn't very gentle although the car keeps driving normally. Other gear shifts are really smooth and you can't feel them unless you are trying to with the reverse of the above shift being slightly more noticeable but still very smooth.

I think it behaved like this ever since I bought it and I've only become sensitive to this behavior in recent weeks (this happens to me a lot), so I'm too not worried but I'm going to take it to the dealership anyway. The Hyundai dealership near me is booked for the next couple of weeks and then I'll be traveling for a week so it'll be a while before I get the chance.

So in the meantime, I'd like to ask if this is a rather normal behavior for this model and if anyone has had a similar problem fixed with their car. Thanks.

Comment: by heavier gear, do you mean lower gear? First gear, the lowest, usually is a bit different to the others, as it has to pull  away from stationary.

Comment: Yeah I mean the lowest one, probably the equivalent of gear 1 in a manual transmission here.